# Persist mongodb session between api requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

I'm using [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) as ODM for my nodejs application
Can I persist started mongodb session to storage like redis, for get and continue it later?
For something like this cases -

1. User make request with some data
2. On server we are starting new session, starting transaction on this session and make some changes on database
3. Get an error on server, but does not abort transaction/end session
4. Response user with error and session id
5. User make some changes on request and send corrected data to server with session id
6. Instantiate session from id on server, and we do not start the operation from the beginning, but using the instantiated session and continue from the place where we stopped last time

Mongoose is using [node-mongodb-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native). On it documentation and sources they notice, that clientsession [not meant to be instantiated directly](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/sessions.js#L45).

Can I get around this limitation, or it is bad pratice to use one session through many users requests?

Comment: What do you mean with "session" ?

Comment: @Marc [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Session/)

Comment: I dont understand the question. Why you are not using (as it should be) `connect()` ?!
If you want "persistent" sessions then you need some loadbalancer & "conntrackd" magic <OR> loadbalancing and "sticky sessions" Thats not a mongodb issue. This is a fault from your application design

Comment: @Marc I do not want to "sticky session". My mongodb session will be opened on database, that will be shared between my servers. Client coming to any of my servers with session id -> server instantiate interrupted session  from session id -> and client can continue make actions on this session

Comment: And where is the diffrence to "sitcky session"? "My mongodb session will be opened on database": This sentence makse no sense. You create a connection to a server, not to a database. You cant share a single TCP connection between multiple server. There is only a "seesion" between the client and the server for the duration of a TCP connection.

Comment: Are you saying, if your database write fails, you want it to be able to try again from one of your servers when the user makes the request again ('client can continue make actions on this session')? If so, @Marc has the right idea... because you're using node.js, you can just use auth tokens for user sessions?

Comment: Note: clients talk only to your server.. your server talks to your database. Client does not talk directly to database, which is where I think you have your idea of sessions mixed up. This is the 3 tier model, and is secure this way